# How can I query to find max population of country from countries table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "countries" with `columns -> name,continent,area,popualtion.`
Let's say I want to find the `name` and `population` of the chosen `country` with the highest population.

```
SELECT MAX(population) FROM countries;
```

The example above returns the maximum population.
I want it to also see the name of the country with that population.

```
SELECT name,MAX(population) FROM countries;
```

I am getting the error like below.

> ERROR:  column "countries.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I can't think of another way to do it.
Here is an example of my query.

```
SELECT name,population
FROM countries
WHERE population >= (
SELECT MAX(population) 
FROM countries)
;
```

This query works, but I am also curious why am I getting the error or if anyone knows if there is any better ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Aggregate functions like SUM, MIN,MAX works with group by query

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, population 
FROM countries
ORDER BY population DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You do not need to use GROUP BY because if your records are like as USA, 300.000.000 | Germany, 85.000.000. you have to order the records and take only first record

Comment: Dr. Greek : Deleted my answer as it seems, I didn't understand question quite well.  Better to include reason about error, OP's getting with aggregated function.

Comment: Not problem, I don't want to annoy u :( . Have a nice coding.. :).

Answer (score 1):

`MAX` selects the maximum element from a list of values. In your first query,

```
SELECT MAX(population) FROM countries;
```

the list is formed by extracting the `population` field from all rows in `countries`, and then the maximum is selected. This collapses the list of rows down to a single row containing just the maximum.

In your second query,

```
SELECT name,MAX(population) FROM countries;
```

you (conceptually) get a list of all `name` fields from `countries`, but there's only one `MAX(population)`. The database system doesn't know what to do with this: `SELECT name FROM countries` would return as many rows as there are in `countries`, but `SELECT MAX(population) FROM countries` would only return one row. This doesn't match up; it's unclear how many rows you want returned from this. This is why you get an error.

The error message says you need to either

- use `name` in an aggregate function, which would collapse the list of rows down to a single value, which could be returned along the single `MAX` value, or
- use a `GROUP BY name` clause, which would group the list of countries into entries with equal names first, then compute `MAX(population)` separately for each group. This makes no sense if all your countries have different names.

As far as I know there's no SQL syntax for "select the maximum `population` and then get the `name` field from the same row" (it's not quite clear what this would do anyway because there can be more than one country with a `population` equal to the maximum).

What you can do instead is sort the whole table, then select only fields from the first row:

```
SELECT name, population
FROM countries
ORDER BY population DESC
LIMIT 1
```

(I'm pretty sure Postgres optimizes this so there's no actual sort involved.)

Now if there is more than one country with a maximum population, you'll get a random result (we haven't told the database how to sort rows with equal population).

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of Top keyword for selecting only single record
from countries table.

```
SELECT Top 1 name,population
FROM countries
order by population DESC
```